# Hide or show button when a CollectionView Item is selected in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to show a button to edit/delete an item in the collection view only when selected.

Item selected = BtnEdit and Btn delete display otherwise hide.

I have the following Visual state but not sure how to modify so that I can toggle the visibility of these 2 buttons

```
<Style TargetType="Frame">
<Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
    <VisualStateGroupList>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{DynamicResource MySelectedColor}" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateGroupList>
</Setter>
```

Comment: Have you read VisualState doc, about setting a property on a different control? Use `TargetName` to set `IsVisible` property on those buttons to True/False.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this.

A common method is to add a bool property `Selected` to the Item of your List and implement interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` for your item.
Then we can bind the `Selected` to the property `IsVisible` of your buttons.

Then according to the status of `Selected` ,we can hide or show the button.

Please refer to the following code:

```
public class ProductDetail: INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {
        public string ProductName{ get; set; }
  
        // add property here
        public Boolean _selected;
        public Boolean Selected
        {
            get
            {
                return _selected;
            }
            set
            {
                _selected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }


      // other code

        bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
                return false;
            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

2.add command `SelectedTagChangedCommand` to your viewmodel.

For example:

```
public class TestViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<ProductDetail> Items { get; set; }

        // add command here
        public Command SelectedTagChangedCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command((sender) =>
                {
                    ProductDetail item = sender as ProductDetail;

                    if (item != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Select item in Colletionview = " + item.ProductName);

                        item.Selected= !item.Selected;

                        foreach (ProductDetail model in Items)
                        {
                            //here we can change the value of `Selected` 
                            if ( model!=item)
                            {
                                model.Selected = false;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        public ICommand QuantityAddCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand QuantityMinusCommand { get; set; }

        public TestViewModel() {
            Items= new ObservableCollection<ProductDetail>();
            Items.Add(new ProductDetail {  ProductName="Product1", Quantity = "30", QuantityOld="10",QuantityNew="0" });
            Items.Add(new ProductDetail { ProductName = "Product2", Quantity = "40", QuantityOld = "10", QuantityNew = "0" });
            Items.Add(new ProductDetail { ProductName = "Product3", Quantity = "50", QuantityOld = "10", QuantityNew = "0" });

            QuantityAddCommand = new Command((object item) => {

                if (item != null && item is ProductDetail) {
                    ProductDetail productdetail = (ProductDetail)item;
                    
                
                }
            });

            QuantityMinusCommand = new Command((object item) => {
                if (item != null && item is ProductDetail)
                {

                    ProductDetail productdetail = (ProductDetail)item;

                   
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

3.Usage example:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:formcollectionviewapp="clr-namespace:FormCollectionViewApp"
             x:Class="FormCollectionViewApp.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <formcollectionviewapp:TestViewModel></formcollectionviewapp:TestViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="StackLayout">
            <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
                <VisualStateGroupList>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                        <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" 
                                        Value="LightSkyBlue" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateGroupList>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <CollectionView  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" x:Name="myCollectionView" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding  SelectedTagChangedCommand}" SelectionChangedCommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, Source={x:Reference myCollectionView}}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">

                    <Label Text="{Binding ProductName}"></Label>

                    <Entry x:Name="txtQuantity" IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding Quantity}" />

                    <Entry x:Name="txtQuantityOld" IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding QuantityOld}" />


                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"  IsVisible="{Binding Selected}"   >
                        <Button    
                                        x:Name="minusbutton" Text="minus"
                                        Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference myCollectionView}, Path=BindingContext.QuantityMinusCommand}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                        BackgroundColor="Yellow"/>

                        <Button   Text="add"
                                        ImageSource="Plus.png"
                                        Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference myCollectionView}, Path=BindingContext.QuantityAddCommand}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                        BackgroundColor="Yellow"/>

                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</ContentPage>
```